# Finding a solution in terms of two solution from a differential equation of order 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a homogeneuos differential equation of order 3 like this:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{3}y}{dx^{3}}+P(x)\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+Q(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+R(x)y(x)=0
\end{equation}
If $y_{1},y_{2}$ are solutions from the differential equation. I have to find $y_{3}$ other solution or a formula based on $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$. I've searching but variation of parameters doesn't work, so I found that I need to reduce the order, so, I worked assume a solution $y=u(y_{1}+y_{2})$ as a sum of these solutions but I'm stuck in a differential equation of order 2 so, I'm trying to thinking in some $''y''$ in terms of $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ such that this equation can be reduce to a differential equation of order 1. If you know some way to work this problem. I will appreciate to know it. Thank you.

Comment: $y_3 = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are reals such that $\alpha + \beta = 1$.

Comment: Should the last term also have a factor $y(x)$? The inhomogeneous terms are traditionally put on the right when stating an equation in this generality.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes, I forgot to write.

Comment: @Arastas Why $\alpha + \beta = 1$?

Comment: If $R(x)$ is also multiplied by $y$ then no need for $\alpha+\beta = 1$.

Comment: Can I extend this solution if I have $y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}$ solutions for a homogeneous ODE of order 4? like $y_{4}=\alpha y_{1}+ \beta y_{2} +\gamma y_{3}$